# Making Bootstrap input look like input-sm in selectize.js component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a selectize component which looks like this.
[image]

My goal is to make the search input look smaller, in other words, change its class from standard bootstrap input to [input-sm](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp).
I guess I have to edit the source code, only where and how - could you please help me with this? It's been already four months since I've been coming back to this issue now and then.

JS:

```
vendors_name_selectize = $('#vendors_name_input').selectize({
            maxItems: 100,
            preload: true,
            openOnFocus:true,
            valueField: 'value',
            labelField: 'text',
            searchField: ['text', 'inn', 'kpp'],
        })[0].selectize;
```

HTML:

```
<th style = 'width:20%' class = 'vendor_list_official_name'>
                        <div class="input-group zeon-column-search">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    Название
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu zeon-dropdown-wide">  
                                    <select id="vendors_name_input" placeholder="Поиск">
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </th>
```

By the way, there's no point building up a JSFiddle, because in JS Fiddle the size of the input differs from that of the element I see in my app

Answer (score 0):

The `input` is wrapped inside a container that has padding and border. The `input` itself has its CSS reset by `selectize.default.css` (this may be different for other selectize themes). However, you can control the element's height with this CSS:

```
.selectize-input { padding: 0; }
```

Additionally you can make the font-size of input smaller for more height reduction:

```
.selectize-input>input { font-size: 10px; }
```

Use `!important` if you have to. The CSS should work if it's cascaded properly.

**DEMO**

```js
// bootstrap 3.3.6
// jquery 2.2.1
// fontawesome 4.5.0

vendors_name_selectize = $('#vendors_name_input').selectize({
  maxItems: 100,
  preload: true,
  openOnFocus: true,
  valueField: 'value',
  labelField: 'text',
  searchField: ['text', 'inn', 'kpp'],
})[0].selectize;
```

```css
.open>.dropdown-menu { padding: 0.5em; }

.selectize-input { padding: 0 !important; }

.selectize-input>input { font-size: 10px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.2/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.2/css/selectize.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<th style='width:20%' class='vendor_list_official_name'>
  <div class="input-group zeon-column-search">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Название
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu zeon-dropdown-wide">
        <select id="vendors_name_input" placeholder="Поиск">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</th>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/dh725pd3/